# angula 5 material odd even list identify by class

Tags: angular

I am using angular material [data table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) and how to add odd even class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution as given using css.

```
.mat-row:nth-child(even){
background-color:#fff;
}

.mat-row:nth-child(odd){
background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your  define isEven and isOdd and use the class attributes.

Sample code below

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let isEven=even;let isOdd=odd;" [class.even]="isEven" [class.odd]="isOdd">
```

Css should hold

```
.even {
  background-color: blue;
}

.odd {
  background-color: pink;
}
```